# What can I do about this fern?

Tags: identification, ferns

Bought a house this winter and I am not sure what this fern is, or how to stop it from taking over. It is growing in two areas, and in one month it went from a dozen or so small stalks to  completely taking over both areas. It is so thick, the smaller flowers that came in earlier are total engulfed in these.

I do like the way these look, but they are way too thick for me and seem to spread very fast. They keep springing up in the lawn, but I pull those as soon as I see them.

I would love to identify this type of fern, and know if I can contain it and trim it back. It would be nice to have some of them, but not at the cost of everything else getting absorbed into them.

[image: Taking over this whole area]

[image: All flowers in here are now gone]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice house as well, it seems!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [ostrich fern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matteuccia_struthiopteris) Matteuccia struthiopteris.  I won't have it in my garden as it is too aggressive.  If you don't like it, you can pull it out or eat it!

> The tightly wound immature fronds, called fiddleheads, are also used
>   as a cooked vegetable, and are considered a delicacy mainly in rural
>   areas of northeastern North America.

The best way to contain it would be to put a physical barrier down.  Pond liner comes to mind...dug in six to eight inches deep around the bed.

Comment: Thanks, I might have to taste one before tearing them out. Would suck to find out I like them only after getting rid of them all :)

Comment: We had these when I lived in Maine as a kid. Brings back fiddlehead memories.

Comment: I thought fiddleheads were only to be eaten young/immature, and are inedible once they're folded out?

Comment: @bstpierre Quite right, only the new fiddleheads are edible. From the picture these ferns look to have grown out too much to be edible.